# SQL Server not listed under connections

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I installed SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU, i can connect to sql server management and query my database, but when i want to add a new ado.net entity data model my server name dropdown is empty.

I get entity framework 6.x from nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server name depends on how you installed SQLExpress. Two possible configurations for the instance:

Default instance:
You named it, and Hopefully enough you can address it with "." as name for the server.

Named instance (chosen by default):
The Server is called SQLEXPRESS, try and type it as the Server name and see if something happens.

Source: http://www.soheib.com/technical-knowledge/sql-server-2012-express-installation-tutorial/